# Python - How to process a binary image to align sparse letters in a row

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, captcha, python-tesseract

I'm trying to align letters from an image in order to obtain the full word with tesseract OCR:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("captcha.png", 0)
h1, w1 = img.shape
img = cv2.resize(img, (w1*5, h1*5))
# Threshold the image and find the contours
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 123, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Create a white background iamge to paste the letters on
bg = np.zeros((200, 200), np.uint8)
bg[:] = 255
left = 5

# Iterate through the contours
for contour, h in zip(contours, hierarchy[0]):
    # Ignore inside parts (circle in a 'p' or 'b')
    if h[3] == -1:
        # Get the bounding rectangle
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        # Paste it onto the background
        bg[5:5+h, left:left+w] = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        left += (w + 5)
cv2.imshow('thresh', bg)
cv2.waitKey()
```

And the image that I want to process is this one

[image]

However, I got this message:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\img.py", line 24, in <module>
    bg[5:5+h, left:left+w] = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (72,750) into shape (72,195)
```

Just with tesseract OCR I got "acba" without the zero and four so I need to reorder the letters to obtain it. Any suggestions?

Comment: You got this error because the left hand side and the right and side does not have the same shape. This is certainly because the 2D slice goes beyond the boundaries of the array.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to check shapes `bg[5:5+h, left:left+w].shape` and `img[y:y+h, x:x+w].shape`. They have to be the same. You may have to get `min()` for `w` and `h` for both objects and get `min_w, min_h` and use in `bg[5:5+min_h, left:left+min_w] = img[y:y+min_h, x:x+min_w]`

Answer (score 1):

You try to put bigger image in smaller area - but they have to be the same.

You may get shapes for both objects and get `min()` for width and height and use it

```
        h1, w1 = bg[5:5+h, left:left+w].shape
        h2, w2 = img[y:y+h, x:x+w].shape
        
        min_h = min(h1, h2)
        min_w = min(w1, w2)
        
        bg[5:5+min_h, left:left+min_w] = img[y:y+min_h, x:x+min_w]
```

---

**EDIT:**

OR maybe you should use `x,y` instead of `5` and `left` (also `5`)

```
        bg[y:y+h, x:x+w] = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

And maybe you should create `bg` with the same size as `img` (after resizing)

```
h1, w1 = img.shape

bg = np.zeros((h1, w1), np.uint8)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code with other changes.

I read image in RGB to see what contours it found because it seems it found something different then you may expect.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

print('CV:', cv2.__version__)

img_color = cv2.imread("ZzSgt.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
h, w = img_color.shape[:2]
print('original shape (W,H):', w, h)

img_color = cv2.resize(img_color, (w*5, h*5))
h, w = img_color.shape[:2]
print('resized shape (W,H) :', w, h)

img = cv2.cvtColor(img_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                       
# Threshold the image and find the contours
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 123, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Create a white background image to paste the letters on
bg = np.full((h, w), 255, np.uint8)

# Create image to display contours 
img_contours = np.full((h, w, 3), 255, np.uint8)

left = 5

# Iterate through the contours
for contour, h in zip(contours, hierarchy[0]):
    # Ignore inside parts (circle in a 'p' or 'b')
    if h[3] == -1:

        # Get the bounding rectangle
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        print('contour (X,Y,W,H):', x, y, w, h)

        # Paste it onto the background
        h1, w1 = bg[5:5+h, left:left+w].shape
        h2, w2 = img[y:y+h, x:x+w].shape
        
        min_h = min(h1, h2)
        min_w = min(w1, w2)
        
        bg[5:5+min_h, left:left+min_w] = img[y:y+min_h, x:x+min_w]
        
        left += (w + 5)

        # Copy color regions and draw contours        
        img_contours[y:y+h, x:x+w] = img_color[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        img_contours = cv2.drawContours(img_contours, [contour], 0, (0,0,255))

cv2.imshow('contours', img_contours)
cv2.imshow('background', bg)
cv2.waitKey()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**contours**

[image]

**background**

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

I get better result if I revese image `img = ~img` and change threshold from `123` to `30`

**thresh**

[image]

**contours**

[image]

**background**  (and now I see it could have size even `(75, 255)` or safer `(100, 300)`)

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

print('CV:', cv2.__version__)

#img_color = cv2.imread("captcha.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img_color = cv2.imread("ZzSgt.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
h, w = img_color.shape[:2]
print('original shape (W,H):', w, h)

img_color = cv2.resize(img_color, (w*5, h*5))
h, w = img_color.shape[:2]
print('resized shape (W,H) :', w, h)

img = cv2.cvtColor(img_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                       
img = ~img                       
# Threshold the image and find the contours
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Create a white background image to paste the letters on
bg = np.full((h, w), 255, np.uint8)

# Create image to display contours 
img_contours = np.full((h, w, 3), 255, np.uint8)

left = 5

# Iterate through the contours
for contour, h in zip(contours, hierarchy[0]):
    # Ignore inside parts (circle in a 'p' or 'b')
    if h[3] == -1:

        # Get the bounding rectangle
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        print('contour (X,Y,W,H):', x, y, w, h)

        # Paste it onto the background
        h1, w1 = bg[5:5+h, left:left+w].shape
        h2, w2 = img[y:y+h, x:x+w].shape
        
        min_h = min(h1, h2)
        min_w = min(w1, w2)
        
        bg[5:5+min_h, left:left+min_w] = img[y:y+min_h, x:x+min_w]
        
        left += (w + 5)

        # Copy (color) region and draw contour
        img_contours[y:y+h, x:x+w] = img_color[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        img_contours = cv2.drawContours(img_contours, [contour], 0, (0,0,255))

cv2.imshow('contours', img_contours)
cv2.imshow('background', bg)
cv2.waitKey()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```